# What is the best Windows release for bitcoin-qt or bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, windows

I want to run bitcoind on one of my servers. I tried Windows Server 2012 but after a couple of days bitcoind process freezes and I can't even kill the process(Access is denied). I want to reinstall another release of Windows on my server. What is the best option?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what Windows would be helpful, but why would you want to use Windows in the first place? Also this seems to be more of a server administration question than a bitcoin question.

Comment: Yes you are right about windows administration question. But I don't know where can ask that question sorry. I want to use windows because I have wrapper written on .Net.